# Golang assign a map to an interface

Tags: go

I wants to assign a map to an interface where underlying value is of type `map[string]interface`.

```
type Data struct{
  data interface{}
}

result := make(map[string]interface{})
data := Data{
   data:result
}

details := make(map[string]interface{})
details["CreatedFor"] = "dfasfasdf"
details["OwnedBy"] = "fasfsad"
```

How can I insert details value to `data` interface inside `Data` struct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to treat an interface as a map, you need to type check it as a map first.

I've modified your sample code a bit to make it clearer, with inline comments explaining what it does:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    // Data struct containing an interface field.
    type Data struct {
        internal interface{}
    }

    // Assign a map to the field.
    type myMap map[string]interface{}
    data := Data{
        internal: make(myMap),
    }

    // Now, we want to access the field again, but as a map:
    // check that it matches the type we want.
    internalMap, ok := data.internal.(myMap)
    if !ok {
        panic("data.internal is not a map")
    }

    // Now what we have the correct type, we can treat it as a map.
    internalMap["CreatedFor"] = "dfasfasdf"
    internalMap["OwnedBy"] = "fasfsad"

    // Print the overall struct.
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

This outputs:

```
{map[CreatedFor:dfasfasdf OwnedBy:fasfsad]}
```

Comment: That was exactly I am asking only thing is that I wants to extract the underlying value of interface which I did using type assertion